# Height not animating when using percentages

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, transition

I want to make a box expand when it is clicked, which I've achieved. But the transition effect does not work if I use percentage for height, even though the transition work when defined in pixels.

I saved a snippet of the site in this codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JZGWBW

this works:

```
function height(ev, thisElement){
    thisElement.style.height = "200px";
}
```

this does not:

```
function height(ev, thisElement){
    thisElement.style.height = "100%";
}
```

Any ideas as to why this happens?

Comment: Right, because you need specific values when using transitions like this.

Comment: So should I use animations instead to achieve the effect?

Comment: You should read this: https://css-tricks.com/using-css-transitions-auto-dimensions. A few seconds of googling would have brought you to the same page.

Comment: Thank you. 
Googled but must have used bad keywords.

Comment: I tried it with pecentage seem to be working

Comment: @FridayAmeh Oh, what browser?

Comment: @Geuis Using the first technique on the link you provided gave me the desired effect.

Comment: If what you want is to collapse your container to 100% you can try 
    function height(ev, thisElement){ thisElement.style.height = thisElement.scrollHeight+"px"; } If you want to add little more margin bottom you can add the desired pixels.